# jpa 2 criteria with map key and value

Tags: dictionary, jpa, criteria

In my entity I have this field

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable
@MapKeyColumn(name = "SERVER_ID")
@Column(name = "IS_SYNC")
private Map<String, Boolean> serverSyncs = new HashMap<>();
```

I'm trying to get all entities of my table that do not have an entry with the key equals to "serverId" (passed as parameter in my function) or that have an entry but the value is false.

This is what I've done for now

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(clazz);
Root<T> root = criteriaQuery.from(clazz);
MapJoin<T, String, Boolean> mapRoot = root.joinMap("serverSyncs");

List<T> result = session.createQuery(
        criteriaQuery.where(
                builder.or(
                        mapRoot.isNull(),
                        builder.not(mapRoot.key().in(serverId)),
                        builder.and(
                                mapRoot.key().in(serverId),
                                mapRoot.value().in(false)
                        )
                )
        )
).list();
```

The thing is I get this error on my query

> Could not locate CollectionPersister for role : ca.tecsar.core.model.AbstractServerEntity.serverSyncs

Question is : how can I achieve what I want with JPA 2.0 Criteria?

Example of what I need to retrieve

id|SERVER_ID|IS_SYNC
1|0000000001|true
1|0000000002|false
2|0000000003|false

If I ask for SERVER_ID = 3,I should get entity 1 and 2
If I ask for SERVER_ID = 2,I should get entity 1
If I ask for SERVER_ID = 1,I should get nothing

Comment: The `mapJoin.value()` method doesn't actually do anything, they included it for the query to look nicer. Also, `mapRoot.isNull()` refers to the map *value*, not the map itself. I'd try skipping `mapRoot.isNull()` (note that with the criteria API, the default type of join is an `INNER JOIN`, so checking for null value of `serverSync` is redundant). As for the error you're getting, is your entity by any chance involved in an inheritance hierarchy? I think it could be a Hibernate-related bug.

Comment: Hmm so how am I supposed to check for the value? Yes I have my model extending an AbstractServerEntity which is annotated with @MappedSuperclass.

Comment: Well, if you changed the join type to a left join, I *think* the check for a null key would be conclusive. Anyway, try flattening the inheritance hierarchy for this particular entity; if it works, then the issue you're having is most likely a bug

Comment: I think the best way for this case is to write the query / namedquery for optimisation. I'll try this later and write a solution if I found one

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So I couldn't do it with JPA 2 Criteria but I've succeeded with a SQL Query. I have a table named PUNCH and the map table is PUNCH_SERVERSYNCS.

```
SELECT p.PUNCHID
FROM PUNCH p
LEFT JOIN PUNCH_SERVERSYNCS pss
ON p.PUNCHID = pss.PUNCH_PUNCHID
WHERE (pss.IS_SYNC = false AND pss.SERVER_ID = 'Server2')
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT p.PUNCHID FROM PUNCH_SERVERSYNCS pss2 WHERE 
pss2.PUNCH_PUNCHID = p.PUNCHID AND pss2.SERVER_ID = 'Server2')
GROUP BY p.PUNCHID
```

Comment: Hello, he's asking about how to do this with Criteria, not with SQL. Regards